# Problem with unity c# - Object.Destroy not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object, coroutine, destroy

So I am creating many objects in coroutine and of course I want to delete them, but Object.Destroy doesnt work. Any ideas?

```
`public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Obstacle obstaclePrefab;
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnNewObstacle());
    }
    IEnumerator SpawnNewObstacle()
    {
        do
        {
            float range = Random.Range(-2.55f, 3.35f);
            Vector3 position = new Vector3(12.5f, range, -1);
            var obstacle = Instantiate(obstaclePrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
            DestroyImmediate(obstacle);
        }
        while (true);
    }
}`
```

Comment: I only see you calling `DestroyImmediate` ...  What exactly does `not working` mean? Getting any errors in the console?

Comment: i already managed, but thanks

Comment: @Kubaa322, this is not a simple discussion forum. The entire purpose of SO is that we post questions and answers for the benefit of us all, and not just the original poster. If you've figured out a solution to your question yourself, then post an answer with it. If your question is no longer of relevance to you because you've found another way, then let us know this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, instead of `DestroyImmediate` you are using `Object.Destroy`, which is a recommended practice.

Eventually the objects gets destroyed, the destruction is delayed till the objects do not have any refernces.

Especially when you are using coroutines, the execution is paused and the control is returned to the calling code and your objects may be still in use. In that case, the delay in destruction is more visible.

Comment: Nope Destroy takes effect immediately in the scene. Only the deconstructor etc inside the c# object itself is delayed until the Garbage Collector kicks in but latest before the next frame! A user wouldn't see the difference in the scene. It's more a matter of the question at which moment the objects are actually removed e.g. when using loops like `while(transform.childCount > 0){ Destroy(transform.GetChild(0)); }` vs `while(transform.childCount > 0){ DestroyImmediate(transform.GetChild(0)); }` .. the latter works the first crashes your app ;)

Comment: Yes you may be  correct when it comes to scene. But actual destruction is delayed. https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html.."Actual object destruction is always delayed until after the current Update loop, but will always be done before rendering."

Comment: Yep .. exactly what I just said :)